# What is the best semantic way to keep horizontal list items center aligned?

Tags: html, xhtml, css

What is the best semantic way to keep horizontal list items center aligned?

Is it possible to keep the items center aligned of this code

```
 <ul id="items">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>iem3</li>
</ul>

li {list-style:none; font-size:16px; float:left; font-size:14px}
```

I found this way on search http://css-tricks.com/examples/CenterHorizontalListItems/

is there any other better way? without needing extra `div`

Is there any trick to write something for this `ul li {  }` to keep list item center aligned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` applied to the `<li>`s and `text-align:center` applied to the `<ul>` to get the centering. You definitely don't need extra non-semantic markup.

http://jsfiddle.net/Madmartigan/rKqMq/2/

There are other ways that involve float but IMO this way is best. Note that those two display properties behave differently, so you'll have to tune to meet your needs.